# Proving equality between two expression

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

if we define the following function:
$$u(t,x)=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{x-s}{t}e^{\frac{-(x-s)^2}{4\epsilon t}}e^{\frac{-s}{2\epsilon}}ds}{\int_{-\infty}^0e^{\frac{-(x-s)^2}{4\epsilon t}}e^{\frac{-s}{2\epsilon}}ds}$$
I'm stuck in proving that:
$$u(t,x)=\frac{K(t,x)}{1+K(t,x)}$$
With
$$K(t,x)=\frac{erfc(\frac{x-t}{2\sqrt{\epsilon t}})}{erfc(\frac{-x}{2\sqrt{\epsilon t}})}e^{\frac{-(x-t)}{2\epsilon}}$$
and the error function (erfc) defined as follows:
$$erfc(x)=1-\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^se^{-s^2}ds$$
I tried a lot of variable change but none of them worked for me, so I just need any 'hint'.

Comment: The subtitution to use is $u = \frac{x-t}{2\sqrt{\epsilon t}}$. Then complete the square

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst it made the expression big, I don’t think that’s the solution

Comment: Where does this equation comes from?

Comment: @Surb it’s the solution to burgers equation and I was asked to write it, with the error function